# Subscribing to Ktable topic using consumer api

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, ksqldb

For Kafka topics i am able to subscribe and receive messages using confluent consumer api. To Kafka Ktables i am able to subscribe using REST API and http client. so my question is, maybe it is possible to subscribe to Kafka table not via rest api but confluent consumer api?

this is how i subscribe to topic:

```
using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(conf).Build())
        {

            try
            {
                consumer.Subscribe(this.TopicLookup);
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        var cr = consumer.Consume(cts.Token);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Consumed message '{cr.Value}' at: '{cr.TopicPartitionOffset}'.");
                    }
                    catch (ConsumeException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error occured: {e.Error.Reason}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                consumer.Close();
            }
        }
```

and this is how i query KSQL:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent("{ \"ksql\": \"select * from userstream7table;\",\"streamsProperties\": { \"ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset\": \"earliest\"}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/vnd.ksql.v1+json");
            //request.Content.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.ksql.v1+json");
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                using (var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(body))
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }
```

When i create a Ktable with REST/Ksql topic gets created too. If i try to subscribe to it, i don't receive any messages.if i query this Ktable using RESP API i get all the messages. Maybe it is not possible to use thoses topics in standart way?

Answer (score 0):

The table's topic is just a Kafka topic like any other. You can consume this data however you like, including using the consumer api.

The reason you're likely running into errors is likely that you're not setting the correct consumer config.  The most likely culprits are:

- Not seeking to start of topic, i.e. not setting `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`.
- Wrong deserializers configured.  I see your building a consumer with `<Ignore, string>`, i.e. ignore the key and String value.  But is the data in the value a string?  This would depend on your value_format.